# Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-4.0

[image]

I am not able to update to Android Studio 4.0

When I check for updates, it is showing me the below message.

**"Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services."**

Comment: Some plugin can show not compatible but guys can't install/uninstall from IDE, 
You guys can remove from plugin folder

Answer (score 12):

This is the Firebase Services for Android Studio plugin (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12667-firebase-services),
(already stated by the message). 
This does not prevent you from upgrading to the latest version of Android Studio, it just lets you know that this plugin that you have installed is not compatible with the new version. It shouldn't be such a problem, because you can continue using Firebase Services, you just won't be able to add Firebase Services through the assistant - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#assistant

Comment: After updating to 4.0 and restart Android Studio, you will get update option in Event Log for updating Firebase Services plugin.

Comment: Yes there is a new version of the Firebase Services plugin as of Jun 05, 2020, which wasn't available earlier.
So one could use the suggestion notice to update it or update it at anytime by going to Preferences->Plugins and looking for "Firebase Services".
Thanks @Xylo

Comment: I see the error, but no option to upgrade Firebase in Settings > Plugins. My Firebase version is 4.0.0. No idea what this Firebase thing is, though...

Comment: Problem: Some plugins can show not compatible with every startup but guys can't install/uninstall from IDE. If you are facing this, remove it from the plugin folder in user/appData in windows. Example `C:\Users\Qamar\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins`

Answer (score 10):

Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Update Firebase services plugin if update available or Disable the plugin for time being.

The warning will be gone and you can update the Android Studio!

After disabling the plugin, the warning is gone as shown in Image

Comment: In Android Studio 4.0.1 there is no File/Settings menu. Under AndroidStudio/Preferences I can get to the Plugins but there's no option to update the firebase services plugin

Comment: @spartygw: Same here. Firebase version 4.0.0. No idea what this Firebase thing is, though...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Steps...

**1)** In PC go to **->** Control Panel **->** Uninstall Program **->** find Android Studio
**->** Uninstall ANDROID STUDIO..
**[NOTE] :
After Clicking On Uninstall Button, it will give you options, Android Studio will be  already Selected by Default..Do Not Uninstall User Settings ...It will Give You Benefit in Recovering you previous Settings.**

**2)** You can Follow this Link [https://developer.android.com/studio]
and Download Latest Version Of Android Studio 4.0.1 for Windows 64-bit **->** which is (871 MB)

**3)** Open the Downloaded file and Install, after installation it will ask you for two options to select..Just Select **Load Previous Settings**..[**DO NOT Load NEW SETTINGS**]

**4)** Update **Firebase Plugin**

**5)** [[[**Happy Coding**]]]

Comment: for future readers: do not do that in 2022

Answer (score 0):

**Android Application Connection problem with Firebase Solved**

If you have connection problem with Firebase database when you click on connect option within android studio, please add google-service API in your build.gradle.
As part of enabling Google APIs or Firebase services in your Android application you may have to add the google-services plugin to your build.gradle (Project Level) file:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
// ...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Search for Firebase.
2. Uninstall the Firebase Plugin and click on Restart IDE.
3. After restart, check for updates and you will not get that warning.

Answer (score -1):

open build.gradle(:app) change testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13' to 4.12