# Android Studio update to 4.1 warns "Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Firebase Services"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.1

I have Android Studio 4.0.1 on Mac Catalina and want to update to 4.1. I see the warning that Firebase Services plugin is not compatabile.

[image]

I'm aware of this question from upgrading from 3.x to 4.0 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62119156/plugin-incompatible-with-the-new-build-found-firebase-services) but when I look at the plugins under Android Studio -> Preferences I don't see any updates available for the Firebase Services plugin.

[image]

**This shows I have plugin v4.0.0. As far as I can tell that is the last version from Google as of June 4, 2020.**

This is the plugin [homepage](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12667-firebase-services/versions)

[image]

Like most people here, I can't afford to screw with my working development environment. But I do like to stay current with updates. Is there a way to update the plugin manually or is my best solution to install 4.1 alongside the 4.0.1 version?

Answer (score 2):

Don't update. I updated Android Studio to latest version and I can't use some plugins now. There is no solution for this issue. You must wait for developers to update their plugins for compatibility.

Comment: Thank you too.. You can make sure that if plugin has new version at plugin's homepage. The plugin is probably compatible If it is updated after Android Studio 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a false alarm, I ignored it and updated to Android Studio 4.1 anyway and everything builds just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it will work, but you will not be able to use Firebase assistant in Tools. You will have to add and update it manually. Anyway, I have made a desicion to wait for Firebase update. Android Studio 4.1 does not change things critically and I am still happy with 4.0.2. I am sure that it will be fixed in 1-2 weeks